# R ggplot2 - setting breaks when also using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have some more flexibility for setting the breaks on a `ggplot` that has facets.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(1000),
                 group = sample(c(1,2), size=1000, replace = TRUE))
```

The problem is I want to create the breaks based off all of the data for a particular facet, but the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) for breaks says:

> A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output (e.g., a function returned by scales::extended_breaks()). Also accepts rlang lambda function notation.

Note that you just get the *limits* of the data for that facet. Say I want to use the output of `summary` to create my breaks. E.g.:

```
breaks_f <- function(x){ 
  print(x) # included this to confirm I only get limits
  as.numeric(ceiling(summary(x)))
}

dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_density(adjust=.8, color = NA, alpha = .8, fill = 'blue')+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_f) +
  facet_wrap(vars(group), scales = 'free')
```

You'll see if you run this, you'll get breaks that based off taking `summary(c(min, max))` for each facet, *not* all of the data for that facet.

So is there a way to access all of the data within each facet?

Thanks!

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but does changing `scales = 'free'` to `scales = 'free_y`' give you your desired outcome?

Comment: @jared_mamrot No that just makes all the facets have the same breaks, but I still don't have the desired control over the breaks

Comment: 1) you don't need to coerce to numeric in `as.numeric(ceiling(summary(x)))`, `ceiling` already returns a numeric vector; 2) can you describe your expected breaks? When you get `c(min, max)` in the breaks function, those are the extremes of all of the data for that facet and the breaks will or should be between those values, right?

Comment: @RuiBarradas 1. Thanks 2. I'd like breaks for additional stats like mean, median, and the others from summary.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` which allows to

> ... vary labels, breaks, limits, transformations and even axis guides for each panel individually.

Hence, using `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` you could apply your function and set the breaks individually for each panel:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  group = sample(c(1, 2), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

breaks_f <- function(x) {
  print(x) # included this to confirm I only get limits
  as.numeric(ceiling(summary(x)))
}

dt %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
  geom_density(adjust = .8, color = NA, alpha = .8, fill = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(vars(group), scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(x = list(
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_f),
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_f)
  ))
```

[image]

```
#> [1] -2.937358  3.535249
#> [1] -2.937358  3.535249
#> [1] -3.084506  2.959591
#> [1] -3.084506  2.959591
```